# Is it possible to process a camera stream with a native module?

Tags: android, react-native, video-processing

I have a working bit of Android Native code which process video frames on the fly via the CameraX API. The basic workflow is this:

1. User points phone at things
2. Code takes a single frame and processes it then returns a result. While this happens, all other frames are dropped (but the user doesn't notice - they just see smooth video)
3. When available, the result is displayed for the user as on screen text
4. Rinse and repeat

**My app will be in React-Native** but I need to keep this bit of code on Native for performance reasons.

So I'm wondering if I can use a [Native Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro) as a sort of black box that takes in a camera stream and returns results. If so, can I keep the flow as above? I particularly want to avoid the user having to do anything other than point the camera.